# Optimal way of calling model method while iterating a large queryset in Django

Tags: python, django

I have an example model as follows:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #model fields

    def my_model_method_1(self, *args):
        #logic for the method. This involves reverse lookup, fk fetching and calculations

    def my_model_method_2(self, *args):
        #logic for the method. This involves reverse lookup, fk fetching and calculations
```

Now I am generating an excel file that has the data of the above model. I am querying the model using `filter` and `values`.

```
my_model_filter = MyModel.objects.filter(fk_field_1__in=list_of_fk_1_field_ids)

my_model_data = my_model_filter.values(all_fields_here)

my_args = {"start_date": some_start_date, "end_date": some_end_date}

for my_model in my_model_data:
    model_id = my_model["id"]
    my_model_object = my_model_filter.get(id=my_model_id)

    val_1 = my_model_object.my_model_method_1(**my_args)
    val_2 = my_model_object.my_model_method_2(**my_args)

    # other logic
    # the above methods are called again for other calculations.
```

Then the whole data is then converted to excel file. The problem is that calling and getting these methods is taking time. Infact for about 10k instances it is taking about 30 mins to generate the report. I have identified that more time is taking when these methods are called.
So is there anyway where i can speed up calling these methods?

**One way that I reduced the time**

```
for my_model in my_model_data:
    model_id = my_model["id"]
    my_model_object = my_model_filter.get(id=my_model_id)

    val_1 = my_model_object.my_model_method_1(**my_args)
    val_2 = my_model_object.my_model_method_2(**my_args)
    
    my_model["val_1"] = val_1
    my_model["val_2"] = val_2

for my_model in my_model_data:
    model_id = my_model["id"]
    my_model_object = my_model_filter.get(id=my_model_id)

    # other logic
    # just add the values stored in my_model dict from the previous loop here instead of calling the methods again, in the final data structure that will be returned.
```

I do not know why this takes less time but the time taken was around 17 mins.

So what can i do to optimize this?

My apologies for not sharing the original code as I cannot share it due to copyrights.

Comment: You should use prefetch_related/select_related to avoid multiple db queries. You're doing n+1 query things.

Comment: Yes. But how can i prefetch from a model method with args?

Comment: I don't know what you do in these methods and what'll db lookup you're making. So I can't tell you exactly.  Other way could be you use a raw query to fetch the results and do what you want to do, you should try to fetch as much as relevant information in the single query unless there's some issue.

Comment: db lookup is filtering a related fk model based on args and then applying logic based on conditionals. So I have to query them inside those methods itself. All other data is fetched outside these methods only. Everything else takes about 2 mins. Outside of these loops. I actually want to call these methods at once on all the instances. I am looking for such a way.